# How to change scrollbar position when switching chart type in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, scrollbar

Example jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/uzmjvn4t/

I tried changing the scrollablePlotArea props but it didnt work, the scrollbar didnt change from x to yAxis.

```
chart.update({
    chart: {
          type: "spline",
          scrollablePlotArea: {
              minWidth: 800,
              minHeight: undefined,
          }
      },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where this thread will be continued: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14758